# Reading a POST in java

Tags: java, sockets, post

I'm having troubles trying to capture a POST request in a java web server (I'm not allowed to use specific HTTP libraries).

Reading the socket:

```
this.socketIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuilder requestString = new StringBuilder();
int lines = 0;
while ((inputLine = this.socketIn.readLine()) != null && inputLine.length() > 0 && lines < 100) {
    requestString.append(inputLine + "\n");
    lines++;
}
// if (requestString.toString().split("\\n")[0].startsWith("POST")){
//    System.out.println(this.socketIn.readLine());
//}
```

after that, if I do `requestString.toString()` I get the following:

```
POST {{uselessDir}}/ HTTP/1.1
Host: {{myIP}}
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://{{myIP}}/{{uselessDir}}/
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 42
```

so, I tried adding a if at the end of the loop, because of there is a empty line between `Content-Length: 42` and the line I'm looking for, and it blocked reading. In order to ensure using tcpdump I was able to capture also the last line.

```
testData1=someText&testData2=someOtherText
```

maybe the solution is very silly, and I'm not seing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide more detailed code, Doesn't getting any hunch from above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you can use a BufferedInputStream but you must handle the empty line with care:

for example you leave your "readLine" loop when line is empty:

```
while (!(inputLine = this.socketIn.readLine()).equals("")) {
```

inside the loop you must read the content-length:

```
if (inputLine.startsWith("Content-Length: ")) {
    contentLength = Integer.parseInt(inputLine.substring("Content-Length: ".length()));
}
```

and after the loop, you read exactly the number of bytes that you expect, not more:

```
char[] content = new char[contentLength];
this.socketIn.read(content);
System.out.println(new String(content));
```

Comment: Yes, now it have sense.
What I wasn't understanding about the POST request was that, it doesn't end, it doesn't have a line break at the end, so you have to read the last line knowing how much long is it. really, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `&& inputLine.length() > 0` from your while condition. It's causing your while loop to exit at the first blank line. If you want to omit blank lines, rather use the snippet in this location:

```
while ((inputLine = this.socketIn.readLine()) != null && lines < 100) {
    if (inputLine.length() > 0) {
        requestString.append(inputLine + "\n");
        lines++;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the while is only limited by the `inputLine = this.socketIn.readLine()) != null && lines < 100` it blocks trying to read, and the last thing it reads is an empty line, anyway, your algorithm should work, but it doesn't.